# Coldfusion - Subdirectory file not displaying

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Recently set up a new ColdFusion8 server instance on a Win2K8/R2 / IIS7.5 / CF8 Enterprise Hostgator dedicated server and everything seemed to be working, until I browsed to a subdirectory:

http://www.quirkup.com/myQuirkup/

There is an index.cfm in that subdirectory. IIS permits .cfm files. Yet, the index.cfm does not display. I don't get any error, just a blank page, with absolutely nothing in the source.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is IIS set-up to server index.cfm as a default document in that sub-dir?

Is anything being logged in the IIS logs, the CF logs or the JRun logs?

Browsing to http://www.quirkup.com/myQuirkup/foo.cfm (ie: an invalid file name), I am getting a CF 404 error, which does seem like IIS is passing requests to CF, which is a start.

Can you replace whatever the code of index.cfm is with this:

```
<cfset message = "Hello World">
<cfoutput>#message#</cfoutput>
```

And see if that runs.

Do you have an Application.cfc or .cfm in that dir or any ancestor dir that could be interfering?  To verify that there isn't one, put an Application.cfm in that sub-dir with nothing in it (just whilst troubleshooting).

Comment: Yes, if I put a blank application.cfc in the subdirectory, suddenly I can browse the page (albeit with errors related to certain application variables undefined which are defined in the root application.cfc). It must be something in my root application.cfc. After some trouble getting Ajax/JSON working, I was advised to remove the onRequest method from the application.cfc. That fixed the Ajax/JSON issue, but I wonder if it has something to do with this new problem.